# Google Tag Manager: CSS selector for just a segment of text inside a <li> element

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I am attempting to use a CSS selector in Google Tag Manager to track the stock number of a product.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEPnx.png)

The data is in an unordered list, and the stock number is in its own separate **li** element. I do know how to target the li element I want, only it pulls in **"Stock #: 38194"** when I JUST want the stock number. Here's how the code looks:

```
<li><span>Stock #:</span> 38194</li>
```

Is there a way I can format the CSS selector - or perhaps use custom JS - to tell GTM to pull that number outside the span tags, and not the words "Stock #"?

In a perfect world, I could put the stock number in its own set of span tags, and give those an id or class, but I have no access to the back end.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no css selector for textnodes, so you cannot target text that is not wrapped into an element. Probably the easiest way to do this would be to use a DOM variable to return the text node of the li element (being text it will not contain the markup for the span) and then use a custom javascript to replace the unwanted text, so: `{{myDOMvariable}}.replace("Stock #","");`